# `git clone` to $GOPATH without `go get`?

Tags: bash, git, go, sh, developer-tools

With badly formed Go packages, this doesn't work:

```
go get -u
```

How do I `clone` without `go get`, and without manually parsing out the path?

Comment: What do you mean by "badly formed Go packages"? Your answer mentions github, but all github repos are automatically "valid Go packages" (assuming they contain Go code).

Comment: Sometimes the Go code isn't in the root, so you have to specify the subdir (e.g.: `<project_name>/<project_name>/cmd`). Which if you haven't looked thoroughly through the code, you don't know where it is. So a `git clone` would be needed, or you can use my answer instead.

Answer (score -1):

Wrote this little shell function for my purposes, might prove useful to you too:

```
function glone()
{
  IFS='/' read -r _ _ host team repo <<< "$1";
  to_dir="${GOPATH:-$HOME/go}/src/$host/$team/$repo";
  if ! [ -d "$to_dir" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$to_dir";
    git clone "$1" "$to_dir";
  fi
  cd "$to_dir";
}
```

Usage:

```
$ glone https://github.com/bradleyfalzon/gopherci
```